# Query times out when run from ADO.NET but runs fine in Query Analyer

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

On local development machine my query times out indefinitely when run via website (ASP.NET - ADO.NET)
Same query was running just yesterday fine. It runs fine when I execute it from local machine.

I even resorted to rebooting machine. What can it be?

Explanations per requests:

1. Query times out after default 30 seconds (in ADO.NET). If I set it to 0 (indefinite) - it runs indefinitely. In Query analyzer it runs immediately (1 second)
2. Query didn't change. Here is code for view:

.

```
public static List<Shipment> GetShipments(List<string> customerIds, DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo)
{
    try
    {
        var data = new List<Shipment>();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            const string SQL = @"
                    SELECT TOP 1000 SH.ShipmentId, SH.TripId, CASE IsCancelled WHEN 1 THEN 'X' ELSE SH.Status END Status, 
                        SH.FromMunicipality, SH.FromAdministrativeArea, 
                        SH.ToMunicipality, SH.ToAdministrativeArea, 
                        SH.PONumber, SH.ProCodeId, SH.ShipperReferenceNumber, SH.BOLNumber,
                        T.ScheduledPickupDate, T.ScheduledDeliveryDate,
                        CASE WHEN NOT TN.PDFBinary IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END HasPOD
                    FROM dbo.vPcyShipment SH 
                    INNER JOIN dbo.vPcyTrip T ON SH.TripId = T.TripId
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tTripNumber TN ON SH.TripId = TN.TripNumber
                    WHERE SH.CustomerId IN ({0})
                        AND T.ScheduledPickupDate BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
                    ORDER BY T.ScheduledPickupDate DESC";

            var customerParamNames = customerIds.Select((s, i) => "@customer" + i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToArray();
            var customerInClause = string.Join(",", customerParamNames);

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(string.Format(SQL, customerInClause), connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", dateFrom);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", dateTo);
                for (var i = 0; i < customerParamNames.Length; i++)
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(customerParamNames[i], customerIds[i]);
                }

                using (var dataTable = new DataTable())
                {
                    dataTable.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
                    var query = from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                select new Shipment
                                {
                                    ShipmentId = row.Field<string>("ShipmentId"),
                                    TripId = row.Field<string>("TripId"),
                                    PoNo = row.Field<string>("PONumber"),
                                    ProCodeId = row.Field<string>("ProCodeId"),
                                    ShipperRef = row.Field<string>("ShipperReferenceNumber"),
                                    BolNo = row.Field<string>("BOLNumber"),
                                    ProphecyStatusCode = row.Field<string>("Status"),
                                    FromCity = row.Field<string>("FromMunicipality"),
                                    FromState = row.Field<string>"FromAdministrativeArea"),
                                    ToCity = row.Field<string>("ToMunicipality"),
                                    ToState = row.Field<string>("ToAdministrativeArea"),
                                    ScheduledPickup = row.Field<DateTime>("ScheduledPickupDate"),
                                    ScheduledDelivery = row.Field<DateTime>("ScheduledDeliveryDate"),
                                    HasPOD = row.Field<int>("HasPOD")
                        };

                    data.AddRange(query.ToList());
                }
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log(ex);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: We need to see the code and the exception to understand what's going on. Please edit your question.

Comment: "query times out indefinitely" What does this mean? Typically when we say a "query timed out" we mean that it did not finish executing in the time that it was permitted to execute. Given that, "times out indefinitely" doesn't make sense. So, what do you mean?

Comment: See edits. It runs indefinitely from VS2012/C#/ASP.NET context

Comment: asked a bazillion times before in many forms: search for parameter sniffing, cached query plan, statistics ...

Comment: Mitch, yes, it looks like something like that. How can I check for those things?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to go on, but I'd start by changing all of your calls to `.AddWithValue()` to use `.Add()` instead. When you call `.AddWithValue()`, .Net has to guess what the type of your parameter is. If it guesses wrong (and it can), suddenly your query might no longer match with an index, and that speaks to the core of database performance.

Answer (score 0):

Differences in performance between Query Analyzer and ADO.NET are often related to different configuration of the database connection (e.g. ANSI_NULLS).

If you're sure you're using exactly the same query (same customer ids, same date range), you could try playing with ANSI_NULLS and other settings in Query Analyzer to try to reproduce the behavior you're seeing with ADO.NET.